# Is there an EPSG coordinate system with Longitude, Latitude that uses international feet for the elevation (Ellipsoid)?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS am entering data using latitude, longitude and elevation in international feet.  Is there a standard CRS for this?

Comment: As in "worldwide CRS"? You also could enter your data and convert using the field calculator after being done.

Comment: Thanks Erik but the Z value is stored in the geometry and is in "feet".  This is what I want but the CRS is EPSG:4326 which specifies units in meters.   When it gets converted by other software (ArcGIS) to another CRS (EPSG:6499 Mich South) the elevation numbers are multiplied to convert them to feet - which they already are feet.